# terminal output from Python's behave package

Tags: python, bdd

When I run the example feature shown on the [pypi behave page](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/behave) the output isn't quite as I'd hoped: The Given, When and Then output messages are printed once in grey, once in colour. Also strange characters are printed at the start of each coloured line.

screenshot:
[image: http://imgur.com/i2VoF]

When I run a feature that uses Selenium, in addition to the above I get the message: No handlers could be found for logger "selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection"

Any thoughts welcome

Comment: What OS? What console/IDE are you using? Python commandline or IDLE? Can you upload a screenshot to a 3rd party image hosting site (ie http://imgur.com/), and provide a link?

Comment: whoops, sorry, Ubuntu 10.04, GNOME terminal 2.30.2, Python commandline, http://imgur.com/i2VoF

Comment: try this tutorial it will help you http://www.blog.fruiapps.com/2012/11/Behavior-Driven-Development-in-Python-with-Lettuce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's trying to colour the output, but something isn't working (or enabled?). Try running `python -m behave -c`

From configuration.py: (describing the `-c` flag)

```
(('-c', '--no-color'), dict(action='store_false', dest='color',
     help="Disable the use of ANSI color escapes.")),
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot without colouring]

If you'd like colouring to work, I suggest reading [Print in terminal with colors using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python)

You could try modifying the `\behave\formatter\ansi_escapes.py` file with the correct ANSI escapes for your terminal - try using the list of escapes on http://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama